# Handbrake: Getting avio_open2 failed, errno -2 when converting video on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, handbrake

On FreeBSD 9.2. Getting a cryptic error when converting a video using `HandBrakeCLI`.

```
$ HandBrakeCLI --preset "iPad" --input "Wolf.Totem.mkv" --output "/mnt/media/Ad Hoc/Wolf Totem.mp4"
[17:01:21] hb_init: starting libhb thread
HandBrake 0.10.1 (2015051600) - FreeBSD amd64 - https://handbrake.fr
4 CPUs detected
Opening Wolf.Totem.mkv...
[17:01:21] CPU:
[17:01:21]  - logical processor count: 4
[17:01:21] OpenCL: library not available
[17:01:21] hb_scan: path=Wolf.Totem.mkv, title_index=1
libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening Wolf.Totem.mkv/BDMV/index.bdmv
libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening Wolf.Totem.mkv/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
libbluray/bluray.c:2182: nav_get_title_list(Wolf.Totem.mkv) failed
[17:01:21] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.1
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[17:01:21] dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Wolf.Totem.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
    MINOR_VERSION   : 1
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomavc1
    CREATION_TIME   : 2015-03-11 15:09:29
    ENCODER         : Lavf55.37.100
  Duration: 02:01:24.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x560 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:7], 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[17:01:21] scan: decoding previews for title 1
[17:01:21] scan: audio 0x1: aac, rate=48000Hz, bitrate=1 Unknown (AAC) (2.0 ch)
[17:01:21] scan: 10 previews, 1280x560, 23.976 fps, autocrop = 0/0/0/0, aspect 2.29:1, PAR 1:1
[17:01:21] libhb: scan thread found 1 valid title(s)
+ title 1:
  + stream: Wolf.Totem.mkv
  + duration: 02:01:24
  + size: 1280x560, pixel aspect: 1/1, display aspect: 2.29, 23.976 fps
  + autocrop: 0/0/0/0
  + support opencl: no
    + support hwd: not built-in
  + chapters:
    + 1: cells 0->0, 0 blocks, duration 02:01:24
  + audio tracks:
    + 1, Unknown (AAC) (2.0 ch) (iso639-2: und)
  + subtitle tracks:
+ Using preset: iPad
[17:01:21] 1 job(s) to process
[17:01:21] starting job
[17:01:21] work: sanitizing track 1 mixdown Dolby Pro Logic II to Stereo
[17:01:21] sync: expecting 174650 video frames
[17:01:21] work: only 1 chapter, disabling chapter markers
[17:01:21] job configuration:
[17:01:21]  * source
[17:01:21]    + Wolf.Totem.mkv
[17:01:21]    + title 1, chapter(s) 1 to 1
[17:01:21]    + container: matroska,webm
[17:01:21]  * destination
[17:01:21]    + /mnt/media/Ad Hoc/Wolf Totem.mp4
[17:01:21]    + container: MPEG-4 (libavformat)
[17:01:21]  * video track
[17:01:21]    + decoder: h264
[17:01:21]    + filters
[17:01:21]      + Framerate Shaper (2:27000000:900000)
[17:01:21]        + frame rate: 23.976 fps -> peak rate limited to 30.000 fps
[17:01:21]      + Crop and Scale (1280:560:0:0:0:0)
[17:01:21]        + source: 1280 * 560, crop (0/0/0/0): 1280 * 560, scale: 1280 * 560
[17:01:21]    + loose anamorphic
[17:01:21]      + storage dimensions: 1280 * 560, mod 2
[17:01:21]      + pixel aspect ratio: 1 / 1
[17:01:21]      + display dimensions: 1280 * 560
[17:01:21]    + encoder: H.264 (libx264)
[17:01:21]      + preset:  medium
[17:01:21]      + profile: high
[17:01:21]      + level:   3.1
[17:01:21]      + quality: 20.00 (RF)
[17:01:21]  * audio track 1
[17:01:21]    + decoder: Unknown (AAC) (2.0 ch) (track 1, id 0x1)
[17:01:21]      + samplerate: 48000 Hz
[17:01:21]    + mixdown: Stereo
[17:01:21]    + encoder: AAC (libavcodec)
[17:01:21]      + bitrate: 160 kbps, samplerate: 48000 Hz
[17:01:21] reader: first SCR 3780 id 0x0 DTS 3780
[17:01:21] encx264: min-keyint: 24, keyint: 240
[17:01:21] encx264: encoding at constant RF 20.000000
[17:01:21] encx264: unparsed options: level=3.1:vbv-bufsize=17500:vbv-maxrate=17500
x264 [info]: using SAR=1/1
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x264 [info]: profile High, level 3.1
ERROR: avio_open2 failed, errno -2
[17:01:21] work: average encoding speed for job is 0.000000 fps
[17:01:21] sync: got 0 frames, 174650 expected
[17:01:22] render: 0 frames output, 0 dropped and 0 duped for CFR/PFR
[17:01:22] render: lost time: 0 (0 frames)
[17:01:22] render: gained time: 0 (0 frames) (0 not accounted for)
[17:01:22] h264-decoder done: 5 frames, 0 decoder errors, 0 drops
[17:01:22] aac-decoder done: 0 frames, 0 decoder errors, 0 drops
[17:01:22] reader: done. 1 scr changes
[17:01:22] libhb: work result = 3

Encode failed (error 3).
```

Anyone recognize this error and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Errno -2**

```
2 ENOENT No such file or directory. 
A component of a specified pathname did not exist, or the pathname was an empty string.
```

Source: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=errno&sektion=2

In this case it meant:

- You did not type the right filename or file path, or
- **you do not have permission to read** from the file/path you typed.

Comment: Yep, this was it!

Answer (score 3):

Ended up being a permissions problem! It turned out I wasn't owner of the folder I was outputting to. The fix was something like

```
chown $USER folder
```

Comment: @Axsuul Try expanding your answer to provide details how did you fixed the permissions. Or which commands have you used.

Comment: @kenorb hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was able to get passed the crashing by using "advanced settings" to try and slow things down.

It seems to be working

[image: screen shot of "advanced settings"]

I'm not sure if what I've changed may negatively impact the video/audio quality (very novice ;-)

Comment: It might have slowed it down a fair amount--I will report back on performance/quality outcome

Comment: I was able to get past the crashing and it did take a long 'ol time, and it completed, but the picture came out bad, sound seemed okay but image has random blocks of static-like noise throughout. Re-running with another preset that had previously failed and it seems to be working. Eh? I am reading straight from DVD drive (Mac stock 2011) so maybe there was a read error it couldnt overcome? I'll post next results.

Comment: thank you for the corrections Mr. Duck--I'm not such a good tiper :-)